# How to change the headline and footline in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer

I am writing a new documentclass, based on “minimal,” and would like to modify the headline and the footline.

I started to study the output routine, but it is not as clear as plain TeX's output routine, so I am looking for a hint.

Note that I would like to avoid the use of a package like “fancyhdr” and just want to find the LaTeX analogous of the token registers `\headline` and `\footline` used in plain TeX.

Comment: The output routine uses the macros `\@thehead` and `\@thefoot` which are filled through `\@oddhead`, `\@oddfoot`, `\@evenhead` etc. This commands are normally set by `\ps@<pagestyle>` called by `\pagestyle`.

Comment: In addition to @UlrikeFischer's comment, see `texdoc source2e`, page 310 onward. Also, the `minimal` class is not really meant for 'production' use at all: if you want to start from something at all 'sane', use `article`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Offtopic: As you mention source2e: why is source3.pdf neither in texlive nor in miktex?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to start from minimal rather than starting from article? minimal was "designed" to be the minimal file that didn't generate an error when loaded as a documentclass, it wasn't designed to be a useful starting point for further document classes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Probably a script failure when I last did an update to CTAN: I'll investigate. Of course, `interface3` is preferred in most cases as it misses out the implementation, when we hope isn't needed for `expl3` use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Besides the fact that it says “minimal,” I have no special reason to start with “minimal.”  It seems easier to add features as needed rather than to trim everything that I do not need from article—if that trimming is at all possible.

Comment: @user40989 as you are finding, it isn't necessarily easier to add features to a barely working class than to remove (or easier ignore) features that you don't need in a class that has been massively debugged by being used by the majority of latex documents for decades;-)

Comment: Here's an example of defining headers/footers without the use of packages: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158752/how-can-i-add-version-control-info-to-footers-say/158755#158755.  In this example, they can be turned on and off and changed at will.

Answer (score 4):

The output routine uses the macros `\@thehead` and `\@thefoot` which are filled through `\@oddhead`, `\@oddfoot`, `\@evenhead` etc. This commands are normally set by `\ps@<pagestyle>` called by `\pagestyle`.