# Inserting a sentence at the top of the page

Tags: header-footer

I want to insert a sentence (Author's personal copy) at the top of the page which is centered. I don't want a header with line. Just want to add a sentence (**bold** or *italic*). How can I add that for

1. first page only
2. each page

Comment: Check out the `fancyhdr` package; it's pretty easy to just remove that line and an example is given in the documentation.

Comment: Here's another way: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158752/how-can-i-add-version-control-info-to-footers-say/158755#158755

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On only one page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[draw,minimum width=4in,fill=olive!40,text=magenta,font=\LARGE\bfseries] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north)  {Author's personal copy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    Some text comes here

\end{document}
```

[image]

On all pages:

Using `background` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[draw,minimum width=4in,fill=olive!40,text=magenta,font=\LARGE\bfseries] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north)  {Author's personal copy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\begin{document}

    Some text comes here
    \clearpage
    Some text again

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `eso-pic` package with only text as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[minimum width=4in,font=\bfseries] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north)  {Author's personal copy};
    \end{tikzpicture}%

}

\begin{document}

    Some text comes here
    \clearpage
    Some text again

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is fine. Still I need a simple layout without box or color. Just a sentence

Comment: @mahmood See the last code with `eso-pic`. I simplified the node.  You have to remove the options given to `\node`.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) with the following setup:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \makebox[\pdfpagewidth]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height-20pt}{%
      \large Author's personal copy
    }}%
  }%
}
```

The above places the required text `20pt` below the top margin of the page boundary and can be used as-is in the preamble. Use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` for a page-only addition. There's also a `\..FG` option if you want to place content in the `F`ore`G`round (as opposed to the `B`ack`G`round).

Comment: Thanks! To make it possible to have more than one line of text, I swapped \raisebox and \makebox (with their parameters), and replaced \makebox with \parbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `titlesec` package with `pagestyles` option, and define a new page style, say "copy" (the formatting is up to you, to be put in the middle argument of `sethead`:

```
\newpagestyle{copy}{%
\sethead{}{\small Author's personal copy}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}%
```

As a title rule is not asked for, you won't have one. Then call `\pagestyle{copy}` in your preamble (case 2) or `thispagestyle{copy}` at the beginning of your document (case 1).